# layout did not fit in different screen size

Tags: android

I have a layout for a game but it does not fit in different size of screen, although i have

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true">
</supports-screens>
```

in my manifest and my xml file is set to fill_parent.

Here's one of my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainlay"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/menubackground">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cloud"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:background="@drawable/clouds" android:layout_marginTop="130dp"/>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newgame"
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbuttoncontrol1" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/highscores"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbuttoncontrol3" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbuttoncontrol4" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/instructions"
        android:layout_width="164dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbuttoncontrol2" />

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rl_onoff"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/on_btn" android:layout_width="50dp"  android:layout_height="50dp" android:src="@drawable/soundon" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/off_btn" android:layout_width="50dp"  android:layout_height="50dp" android:src="@drawable/soundoff" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageView>
   </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can you help me find why it does not fit in different screen size?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why Dont u use Relative layout instead of linear Layout as parent

Comment: Can you explain what exactly doesn't fit? Are some parts to large or overlap? Perhaps some screenshots would help. One how it should look like and one how it looks on a screen with a different size. Of course you got always the option to provide different layout files for different screen sizes and densities.

Comment: avoid layout_margins & does,n fix height & width

Comment: use wrap_content & fill_parent for height & width

Answer (score 2):

Because supporting it doesn't mean it will autoscale it.
You have to make "different" layouts depending on screensize and screendensity.

read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)